# How to keep the main code separately from index.js electron?

Tags: node.js, directory, electron

Is it possible to keep have this project structure and make it work properly?

[image]

What I wanted to achieve (basic electron structure but the main code is kept within another folder):
Package.json's "start": "..." loads into index.js

index.js loads to index.html which is in the MainCode folder

(please ignore index.py)

This was the beginning code for index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    const path = require ("path");
    win.loadFile (path.join (__dirname, "MainCode", "index.html"));
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

This wasn't the previous code, this the updated one suggested by one of the answers.

And this was of package.json

```
{
  "name": "filler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is to distract you",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
  }
}
```

Edit: I tried doing it as suggested by one of the comments, but I get this error:
<avinav@avinav-Inspiron-5468:~/Documents/PYTHON/helpingTEACHERS!/Filler$ npm start

> filler@1.0.0 start /home/avinav/Documents/PYTHON/helpingTEACHERS!/Filler
> electron .

sh: 1: electron: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! filler@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the filler@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/avinav/.npm/_logs/2021-02-04T14_07_18_026Z-debug.log
I think it has something to do with the package.json, but I don't know exactly what is happening

Comment: I don't see why not, can't speak directly on this but that's never been a concern ever! Not here, not today!

Comment: Just a side note: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit] your question at any time to include your code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load your `index.html` file from the folder `MainCode` into the `BrowserWindow` you're instantiating, you can do so by replacing

```
win.loadFile ("index.html");
```

with

```js
win.loadFile ("MainCode/index.html");
```

However, it is more portable to use the following code:

```js
const path = require ("path");
win.loadFile (path.join (__dirname, "MainCode", "index.html"));
```

This will create a file system path suitable for your OS based upon the current directory (`__dirname` stores the path to the directory the currently executed script is located in under Node.js).

Comment: I too see that this should work, but for some reason, it is giving me an error. I have included the error in the edit. (I suspect package.json but I am not sure)

Comment: I just went through the node-packages, and seemingly electron wasn't installed even though I had run the command for installing it (with sudo) a literal trillion times

Comment: Just did some more research and it worked! Very very thanks!